# Facebook responsive video isn't loading time to time

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, html5-video

I have this code from 2017 here at stackoverflow which shows the Facebook video in a responsive manner. The problem is that it doesn't load most times. There's no error in the console. I tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari. It just shows blank page when it doesn't load.

When it loads, it loads. When it doesn't, it doesn't. No error whatsoever can be seen in the console.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

```
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
<div class="fb-video"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=10155278547321729"
    data-width="auto"
    data-show-captions="false">
</div>
```

This method works perfectly but it's not responsive:

```
<div class="fbVideo">
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/facebookapp/videos/10155278547321729/" width="476" height="476" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: _“Any idea how to resolve this issue?”_ - not unless we can see this reproducibly fail live somewhere. I kinda doubt this fails completely silently.

Comment: _“This method works perfectly but it's not responsive”_ - if you know the aspect ratio you need up-front, iframes can relatively easily be made responsive, using the _padding-bottom hack_.

Comment: Well, it's working on and off on both my laptops. Sometimes, it loads. Sometimes, it doesn't load. So I can't replicate the issue. Yeah, it appears like I have to create different code for different screen sizes.